# Python ModuleNotFound urllib2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently running Python 3.8.0.

I have a program but when executing it, I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError and it points to 'urllib2'

I've tried to fix this issue as this seems to be a common thing, but cannot figure out where I am getting stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Below are the errors and the Python code.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

def main():
    ip = json.loads(urlopen('https://ifconfig.co/json').read())['ip']
    print(json.dumps({'ip': ip + '/32'}))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html: "**The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`.**"

Comment: thank you. I have tried that and have gotten another error. I will edit original with the updated error